# How do I get the perfect format for my calculator?

Tags: c#, winforms, format, calculator, tostring

I built a caculator and I need help at the perfect format for my output.
    I use C#/WindowsForms.
    This is now with the Format N:

```
    100 = 100,00
    1000 = 1.000,00
    more than 999 Trillion = 1.000.000.000.000.000,00 (no 10e+ x)
    0,123456789 = 0,16 (completes after two places)
```

I tried to create a custom format, but it doesn't work the way I want it to.
The format that i want is:

```
    100 = 100
    1000 = 1.000
    1000000 = 1.000.000
    1000000000 = 1.000.000.000 
    higher 999 Trillion = Xe+ X
    0,111111111 = 0,111111111
    and at to much negative range = x.00000000000e -x
```

Long story short.
I need the 10e +/- variant after 999.999.999.999.999
every 3 steps in positive area needs a dot (1.000, 100.000, 1.000.000)
and just one comma for lower numbers (0,00000).
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the format you ultimately want, but by implementing an extension you could set your own rules to achieve the result you want. I'm using the Spaniard CultureInfo because it uses the comma as decimal separator.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string Formatted(this double d)
    {
        if (d >= 1e+15)
        {
            return d.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES"));
        }
        else
        {
            return d.ToString("#,##0.###############", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES"));
        }
    }
}
```

Sample:

```
var testValues = new List<double>()
{
    100,
    1000,
    1000000,
    1000000000,
    1000000000000000,
    0.3,
    0.123456789,
};

foreach (var value in testValues)
{
     Console.WriteLine(value.Formatted());
}
```

> 100
>
> 1.000
>
> 1.000.000
>
> 1.000.000.000
>
> 1E+15
>
> 0,3
>
> 0,123456789

Comment: Thank you. It still doesn't work perfectly. Either only the points or the 10+ work. Depending on whether I use the # or not. But I think I can integrate it as an extra format via menu. Thanks alot :)